# the value of the variable doesn't change in python

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, return

```
def type_():
    z = input("enter an integer : \n")
    try:
        z = int(z)
        a = 1
    except:
        print("it is not an integer")
        a = 0
    return z,a
z,a = type_()
print (z,a)
while a == 0:
    type_()
```

#the code runs good but the issue is when i enter an non integer the while loop gets back to the top but the  value of the "a" doesn't change thereafter,even when i enter an integer,the loop runs infinitely...
kindly help out, thanks in advance

Comment: In your while loop, if you want to update your variables, you should have `z,a = type_()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def type_():
    z = input("enter an integer : \n")
    try:
        z = int(z)
        a = 1
    except:
        print("it is not an integer")
        a = 0
    return z,a
z,a = type_()
print (z,a)
while a == 0:
    z, a = type_() # You forgot to overide the a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign the name `a` in the global scope only once. Names don't magically update, they don't know how or when they should be (re)assigned on their own.

Reassign `a` when calling `type_` in the `while` loop.

```
while a == 0:
    z, a = type_()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing `a` inside the loop, you need to set the value of `z` and `a` each time you run the loop:

```py
while a == 0:
    z, a = type_()
```